# How to provide a value for text field that does not have the value attribute in HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, html, htmlunit, java-6

The HTML element below is part of a form:

```
<input id="code" type="text" name="code" placeholder="Enter code here" autocomplete="off"/>
```

I would like to pass a string to this element. I do not know how to pass a string without a value attribute.

Comment: The same way you would do with any other field.

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Comment: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html#Submitting_a_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to pass the string to the input by using `setText()` method:

```
HtmlTextInput input = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("code");
input.setText("your_text");
```

or `type()` method:

```
HtmlTextInput input = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("code");
input.type("your_text");
```